# How do i use this vulnerability and try and see how exaclty it works?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection, owasp, zap

I am testing my site for vulns and found a SQL Injection SQLites on Owasp Zap

but I don't know how to use sqlmap on that specific URL https:/sample/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1

attack is case randomblob(100000000) when not null then 1 else 1 end --
parameter is ver

how do I use this attack in sqlmap???

Comment: Well it would help us if you provided the full alert details. It seems to be a timing related attack so if you were testing locally or with a underpowered or overbusy server it could easily be a false positive. You'd confirm it as you would any SQLi vuln: attempt to replicate and extend.

Comment: How exactly can i confirm this? i am pretty new to these stuff