# How to test this vulnerability?

Tags: sql, security, owasp, zap, sqlmap

The query time is controllable using parameter value [' | case randomblob(1000000000) when not null then "" else "" end | '], which caused the request to take [142] milliseconds, parameter value [' | case randomblob(1000000000) when not null then "" else "" end | '], which caused the request to take [142] milliseconds, when the original unmodified query with value [24] took [66] milliseconds.

So I found a SQL injection vuln on my site and its
' | case randomblob(1000000000) when not null then "" else "" end | '

my site
https://sample.com/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/result?req_id=6506bd25b9e42c3e

I don't know how to see the database on sqlmap to see if its vuln is that serious how can I test this SQL injection manually??

Comment: This seems to be a re-post of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501858/how-do-i-use-this-vulnerability-and-try-and-see-how-exaclty-it-works

Comment: Yeah i got no support at all so i reposted it

Comment: Not sure that being impatient or acting entitled is going to garner any sympathy from SO, SQLmap, or ZAP communities. You should probably consult a resource like https://owasp.org/wstg or your search engine of choice for info in SQLi exploits and testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use this vulnerability and try and see how exaclty it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501858/how-do-i-use-this-vulnerability-and-try-and-see-how-exaclty-it-works)

Answer (score 0):

the link of the portswigger would help to understand the issue. if your server is delayed because of the request, your db server is vulnerable for SQLi.

https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind/lab-time-delays

https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind/lab-time-delays-info-retrieval